# Original head pointer not being changed in the printList function, but the list does change when inserting a node

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've read these two posts/answers regarding the use of double pointers/passing by reference

[When printing out a linked list, why is the original head pointer not changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577711/when-printing-out-a-linked-list-why-is-the-original-head-pointer-not-changed)

[Linked list head double pointer passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313233/linked-list-head-double-pointer-passing)

but one thing still puzzles me.

The head pointer in printList function (with head = head->next traversal) does not get changed in main, because even though we pass it by reference, the function receives a copy of the pointer/address.
Which I can understand.

But how come then the whole list gets changed (updated) when inserting a node like

```
struct node* addLast(struct node* head, struct node* new_node) {
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new_node;
        return head;
    }

    struct node* current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = new_node;

    return head;
}
```

and we call it in main

```
head = addLast(head, node)
```

I get that the principle applies to the case when head == NULL (because we return the "new" head), but if not, then we traverse the list again and insert the node.

How come then that the list gets updated (not necessarily in this particular add function only)? Is it not then that the new_node (node created by another function with malloc()) is also a "copy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how come then the whole list gets changed (updated) when inserting a node?

As you rightly remark, there are two cases here:

> I get that the principle applies to the case when head == NULL (because we return the "new" head)

Indeed. So your question is about the remaining cases where the list is not empty and a node is appended to it.

In that case the returned value is the same *pointer* as was given as argument: `head` does not change.

However, the node that `head` points to has its own `next` pointer, and *that* pointer might have changed from `NULL` to a pointer to the new node. So, although `head` does not change, the chain of `next` pointers will have become *longer*.

Just visualise what happens when we start with an empty list, and then add nodes to it with the following script:

```
node* createNode(int value) {
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

int main() {
    node* head = NULL;
    head = addLast(head, createNode(1));
    head = addLast(head, createNode(2));
    head = addLast(head, createNode(3));
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

I just added a function to create a node instance: no surprises there (I hope!)

So when the script starts, we have `head`:

```
head: NULL
```

Then we call `createNode(1)` which returns a pointer to a node. We can represent that node with a box:

```
┌────────────┐
│ value: 1   │
│ next: NULL │
└────────────┘
```

The pointer to this node is passed as second argument to `addList`, so in that function we have:

```
 new_node         head: NULL
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ value: 1   │
│ next: NULL │
└────────────┘
```

As you correctly noticed, this node reference is returned from the function `addList` to the caller, and the caller assigns it to its own `head` variable. So in the main program we now have this state:

```
 head
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ value: 1   │ 
│ next: NULL │
└────────────┘
```

Now to the second node: it is created with `createNode(2)`, and then `addList` is called with these arguments:

```
 head                new_node
  ↓                   ↓
┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ value: 1   │      │ value: 2   │ 
│ next: NULL │      │ next: NULL │
└────────────┘      └────────────┘
```

`addList` then creates another variable `current` which starts out with the same reference as `head`:

```
 current
 head                new_node
  ↓                   ↓
┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ value: 1   │      │ value: 2   │ 
│ next: NULL │      │ next: NULL │
└────────────┘      └────────────┘
```

The `while` loop condition is not true, so it will not iterate. Then `current->next = new_node` is executed, and this is the most important assignment: it establishes the link between the *last* node of the list with the new node:

```
 current
 head                new_node
  ↓                   ↓
┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ value: 1   │      │ value: 2   │ 
│ next: ──────────> │ next: NULL │
└────────────┘      └────────────┘
```

And finally, `head` is returned to the caller, who assigns it to their `head` variable -- this is really a dummy assignment, because `head` didn't change. What *did* change is the length of the linked list that `head` points to.

This should explain it, but let's just add one more node: `create_node(3)` is passed to `addList`, so in `addList` we have this state:

```
 current
 head                                    new_node
  ↓                                       ↓
┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ value: 1   │      │ value: 2   │      │ value: 3   │ 
│ next: ──────────> │ next: NULL │      │ next: NULL │
└────────────┘      └────────────┘      └────────────┘
```

This time the `while` condition is true, so `current = current->next` will bring us into this state:

```
 head                current             new_node
  ↓                   ↓                   ↓
┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ value: 1   │      │ value: 2   │      │ value: 3   │ 
│ next: ──────────> │ next: NULL │      │ next: NULL │
└────────────┘      └────────────┘      └────────────┘
```

The `while` loop will then exit, and `current->next = new_node` gets executed:

```
 head                current             new_node
  ↓                   ↓                   ↓
┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ value: 1   │      │ value: 2   │      │ value: 3   │ 
│ next: ──────────> │ next: ──────────> │ next: NULL │
└────────────┘      └────────────┘      └────────────┘
```

And `addList` terminates by returning the (unchanged) `head` pointer. The main program performs again the assignment to its own `head` even though there was no change to that pointer.

I hope this clarifies that even though `head` does not change anymore, the chain of `next` pointers *does* change: the tail node's `next` pointer changes from `NULL` to the address of the new node.

Comment: Thank you for this visual and very detailed explanation! I do understand, which is why i was confused about the printList function; because in that function, while traversing, we do assign the head->next to our head pointer (head = head->next). Does the head pointer in that case remain unchanged because we usually do not use the return value (in most cases I've come across it is a void function), or pointer to head pointer in printList functions, we rather just "go" through it?

Comment: It remains unchanged, because `head` is a local variable, and assigning to it does not modify the other variable with the same name in `main`, whose value was passed as argument.

Comment: Ah, I see. It’s clear now, and once more, I truly appreciate the time and detailed clarification.